# Mocha.js: async function breaks the nested structure

Tags: javascript, async-await, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

When testing a result of async function, using mocha, the tests that comes after `await` pops out of the nested structure, like the first 2 tests below:

```
✓ email
✓ phone
current unit
    fetch data
    ✓ is 5==5

3 passing (10ms)
```

How can we make the tests to appear in their proper place?

The code:

```
const chai = require('chai');
chai.should();

describe ("current unit", async () => {    
    describe ("fetch data", async () => {    
        it ("is 5==5", () => { chai.expect(5).to.equal(5); });

        const UserData = await getUserData("UserName");

        it ("email", () => { UserData.email.should.equal("example@g.com"); });
        it ("phone", () => { UserData.phone.should.equal("+1 (800) 123 4567"); });
    });
});

function getUserData(param) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({ email:"example@g.com",phone:"+1 (800) 123 4567" }), 1/*ms*/));}
```

Comment: It's usually better to put your setup code inside a `before` or `beforeEach`

Comment: `before()` accepts async functions as well, so you can do `let UserData; before(async () => { UserData = await getUserData()  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your test file using `before`

```js
const chai = require('chai');
chai.should();

describe ("current unit", async () => {    
    describe ("fetch data", async () => {    
        let UserData
        before(async () => {
            UserData = await getUserData("UserName");
        })
        it ("is 5==5", () => { chai.expect(5).to.equal(5); });
        it ("email", () => { UserData.email.should.equal("example@g.com"); });
        it ("phone", () => { UserData.phone.should.equal("+1 (800) 123 4567"); });
    });
});

function getUserData(param) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve({ email:"example@g.com",phone:"+1 (800) 123 4567" }), 1/*ms*/));}
```

Here is the output for the above test

```
  current unit
    fetch data
      ✓ is 5==5
      ✓ email
      ✓ phone
```

You can make the tests appear in their proper place by using a `before` expression in the "fetch data" test suite

Answer (score 1):

If you "convert" your code from `async/await` syntax to Promise syntax, it will look more clear to explain:

```
describe("current unit", () => {
  describe("fetch data", () => {
    it("is 5==5", () => { chai.expect(5).to.equal(5); });

    getUserData("UserName")
      .then(UserData => {
        it("email", () => { UserData.email.should.equal("example@g.com"); });
        it("phone", () => { UserData.phone.should.equal("+1 (800) 123 4567"); });
      });
  });
});
```

As you can see, "fetch data" just includes `is 5==5`, and `email`, `phone` specs are in another scope (in this case the scope is `free describe`) then these specs will be appear on the top.

`getUserData` just "waits" 1ms, then you can see `email`, `phone` spec, if you increase the value to 100ms (or higher) you will not these specs, because `getUserData().then` is a synchronous block.

Never call async action in body of `describe` directly, let use `beforeEach`, or write it in the body of `it`.

Use `beforeEach`:

```
describe("current unit", () => { // remove async keyword, it does not make sense
  let UserData; // define variable
  beforeEach(async () => { // async
    UserData = await getUserData("UserName"); // init
  });

  describe("fetch data", () => { // remove async keyword
    it("is 5==5", () => { chai.expect(5).to.equal(5); });
    it("email", () => { UserData.email.should.equal("example@g.com"); });
    it("phone", () => { UserData.phone.should.equal("+1 (800) 123 4567"); });
  });
});
```

```
  current unit
    fetch data
      ✓ is 5==5
      ✓ email
      ✓ phone
  3 passing (357ms)
```

Write in `it` block:

```
describe("current unit", () => { // remove async keyword, it does not make sense
  describe("fetch data", () => { // remove async keyword
    it("is 5==5", () => { chai.expect(5).to.equal(5); });
    it("should return correct email and phone", async () => { // compile into 1 spec
      const UserData = await getUserData("UserName");
      UserData.email.should.equal("example@g.com");
      UserData.phone.should.equal("+1 (800) 123 4567");
    });
  });
});
```

```
  current unit
    fetch data
      ✓ is 5==5
      ✓ should return correct email and phone (108ms)
  2 passing (149ms)
```

Comment: Thank you. But it should be `before`, instead of `beforeEach`. My real function takes long time to run, and i'm checking much more than 2 properties.

Comment: @Dani-Br The task of the unit test takes long time to run? Some thinh went wrong. BTW, you can use `beforeAll` instead of `beforeEach`, `beforeAll` just executes once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `done()` function after the async parts of your test. Here's an example:

```js
it ("email", (done) => {
  UserData.email.should.equal("example@g.com");
  done();
});
```