# before() does not synchronize on a nested describe()

Tags: mocha.js

My tests require a promise to be resolved before they start. I have the following:

- before() hook with the asynchronous call
- a test on the same level as the before() hook
- a group of level 2 tests grouped in a nested describe()

The level1 test is correctly synchronized on the promise in the before() hook.
However the describe() group is not. Why not and how to synchronize it?

```
describe('My tests)=> {

  const thePromise$ = (asynchronous call here)

  before(async () => await thePromise$)

  beforeEach(async () => await thePromise$) //an extra safeguard?

  if('Test Level1', ()=> {
   console.log('Test1')
   //won't start until thePromise$ is resolved, excatly as I want
  })

  describe('Level2 Test group', ()={
    console.log('Level2 test group')
    //starts right away, does not wait for the promise to be resolved
  })
})
```

Comment: Try to use `beforeEach` instead of `before`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61958572/65232

Comment: Still doesn't work, updated the question with the new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I not find a solution to this specific question, I found a way to get done what I really needed, which prompted the question to begin with: how to generate it() tests out of test data that require an asynchronous call to retrieve.

[how to generate it() tests after waiting on an asynchronous response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72820429/how-to-generate-it-tests-after-waiting-on-an-asynchronous-response/72821116#72821116)